# Is AvroIO.writeGenericRecords(schema) capable to append to existing files in java?

Tags: java, avro

I have been scratching my head around this question for a while, I'm using java with Avro, writing files with windowed writes, shards, & shard template "W-P-sssss-of-nnnnn", but now the requirement ask for appending the content to the existing amount of shards.

```
PCollection<GenericRecord> collection = ...
collection.apply("write to bucket", 
AvroIO.writeGenericRecords(schema)
.to("gs://my-bucket/folder")
.withWindowedWrites()
.withNumShards(20)
.withShardNameTemplate("ssss-of-nnnn"));
```

I understand that shard number will attempt to create 20 files, but those will increase if more data is present. I has been trying to append to existing content, but I only get files being overwritten.

Of course, if we set a more unique shard template, like "W-P-sssss-of-nnnnn" we get more files, avoiding the files being overwritten, but, how to append data to existing 20 shards?
Is that possible?

I tried using with Dynamic Destinations, and Value providers, but that allowed me to manipulate the folder destination, or the file naming policy, but this don't put me closer to defining how to append instead of overwriting files.

Comment: So far, I can say that .withShardNameTemplate("ssss-of-nnnn") causes issues for name uniqueness. if I reduce the number of chards & increase the window size, I can get files containing more than 1 avro object.

Comment: So, my recommendation, do not use
.withNumShards(20) &
.withShardNameTemplate("ssss-of-nnnn"));

Answer (score 0):

Avro will handle itself the amount of data created and sent to the bucket, along with appending data, as long as you don't mess with its file naming convention. Also you need enough data in order to do your tests.

Comment: TL;DR: a lower num chards will create less files, containing more data.